# How to make loop in loop (double loop)

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer

i have problem with loop.

i have code like this,

```
foreach ($j as $empas) {


    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $nomor = Nomor($i, $total);
    $proses = proses($total, $i) . "%";
    $timeServer = date("G:i:s");
    $toDay = date("d-M-Y");
    for($p=0;$p<$total;$p++){
        $user = $userlist[$p%count($userlist)] ;


        echo "\e[37m [" . $timeServer . "] - {$nomor}/{$total} - [{$proses}] {$user} > {$empas}  \e[0m ";;
        if (isEmail($empas)) {
            echo imakochan($empas, $letter, $host, $user, $pw, $port, $sendermail, $sendername, $subjek). "\n";
            } else {
        echo " This is not valid email ";
    }

    if ($i == $total) {
        echo "\n";
        echo " [0;34m ================================================================================== \n";
        echo " [0;34m [+]            Sending Proccess Completed on " . $timeServer . "            [+]\n";
    }
     $i++;
 } 
}
```

so , my problem is i can't rotate smtp when the php mailer send email.

i want smtp rotate by email ,it should be rotate by email

like this

smtpuser1 > email1 ->sent!

smtpuser2 > email2 ->sent!

smtpuser1 > email3 ->sent!

smtpuser2 > email4 ->sent!

when i do like this, i've got problem :

```
[17:01:42] - 1/2 - [50%] smtpuser1 > focusedamos@hotmail.com   -> Sent!

[17:01:42] - 1/2 - [50%] smtpuser2 > focusedamos@hotmail.com   -> Sent!

  ==================================================================================
  [+]            Sending Proccess Completed on 17:01:42            [+]
 [17:01:50] - 3/2 - [150%] smtpuser1 > asowchizuru09@hotmail.com   -> Sent!
 [17:01:50] - 3/2 - [150%] smtpuser2 > asowchizuru09@hotmail.com   -> Sent!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do a double loop for this. Think, when you use a double loop (loop inside a loop), the loop inside will run completely on each run of the external loop.

Example:

```
loop1 : run 5 times
  loop2: run 2 times
```

Result:

```
loop1 run1
  loop2 run1
  loop2 run2
loop1 run2
  loop2 run1
  loop2 run2
loop1 run3
  loop2 run1
  loop2 run2
loop1 run4
  loop2 run1
  loop2 run2
loop1 run5
  loop2 run1
  loop2 run2
```

To accomplish what are you trying, use a more simple approach. For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$smtpArray = array(0 => 'smtp1.example.com', 1 => 'smtp2.example.com', 2 => 'smtp3.example.com');
$smtpCount = count($smtpArray);
$i = 0;
foreach ($j as $empas) {
    $nomor = Nomor($i, $total);
    $proses = proses($total, $i) . "%";
    $timeServer = date("G:i:s");
    $toDay = date("d-M-Y");
    $iteration = $i % $smtpCount; // Create a number of SMTP server to iterate it.
    $smtp = $smtpArray[$iteration]; // Use the SMTP server selected before.

    echo "\e[37m [" . $timeServer . "] - {$nomor}/{$total} - [{$proses}] {$smtp} > {$empas}  \e[0m ";
    if (isEmail($empas)) {
        echo imakochan($empas, $letter, $host, $smtp, $pw, $port, $sendermail, $sendername, $subjek). "\n";
    } else {
        echo " This is not valid email ";
    }

    if ($i == $total) {
        echo "\n";
        echo " [0;34m ================================================================================== \n";
        echo " [0;34m [+]            Sending Proccess Completed on " . $timeServer . "            [+]\n";
    }
    $i++; // Increase $i to use next SMTP server on next iteration.
}
```

I've get out the timezone set because you didn't need to set every run of the loop.

Comment: what function for $user ?

Comment: I've forgot to delete $user variable. I've replace it with $smtp variable, more descriptive for their use.

Comment: in my code, i use $i = 1;, but u use it for 0. how i change it ?
because i use it for print complete banner.

Comment: It's OK if you start $i on 1, because, on my code I'm using $i % $arrayCount, who returns the rest of the division.

Comment: so i make  int $p = 0;
but the result is

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$p' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: It's my error, use $p = 0; or $i = 0;, don't define variable type.

Comment: Also, I've said before, you don't need to use a second variable, you can use $i on whatever start value you use, but, always if you increment it on steps of one.